# Improving the implementation of the timer(timeout event) in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

My case looks like this: The program uses two threads, let's call them "Sender" and "Recipient" because it is a mechanism of interprocess communication.

The "Sender" thread after sending the message stops at the condition provided by `std::condition_variable` and the `.wait (Lock)` function. The "Recipient" thread informs the waiting thread about the response to his message using `.notify_one()`.

I'm happy with the way it works, but I want to add the ability to handle the timeout.

I prepared the following class (I would like it to be universal so the notification function is defined from the external class) but I'm sure that it can be implemented better. I wanted to avoid a lot of CPU usage, that's why I used `std::this_thread::sleep_for`, but I suppose that it can be somehow replaced with `std::this_thread::yield()`. I would like to use eg `std::future_status`, but I do not know how to do it. How can this be improved? I can use std `c++11` or `boost 1.55`.

```
class Timer
{
    private:
    int MsLimit;
    std::atomic<bool> Stop;
    std::atomic<bool> LimitReached;
    std::thread T;
    std::mutex M;
    std::function<void()> NotifyWaitingThreadFunction;

    void Timeout()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> Lock(M);
        std::chrono::system_clock::time_point TimerStart = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<long long, std::milli> ElapsedTime;
        unsigned int T = 0;
        do
        {   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5));
            std::chrono::system_clock::time_point TimerEnd = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
            ElapsedTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(TimerEnd - TimerStart);
            T+=ElapsedTime.count();
            if((T > MsLimit) && (!Stop))
            {   LimitReached = true;
                Stop = true;
            }
        }while(!Stop);

        if(LimitReached)
        {
            NotifyWaitingThreadFunction();
        }
    }

    public:
    Timer(int Milliseconds) : MsLimit(Milliseconds)
    {

    }
    void StartTimer()
    {
        Stop = false;
        LimitReached = false;
        T = std::thread(&Timer::Timeout,this);
    }
    void StopTimer()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> Lock(M);
        Stop = true;
        LimitReached = false;
    }
    template<class T>
    void AssignFunction(T* ObjectInstance, void (T::*MemberFunction)())
    {
        NotifyWaitingThreadFunction = std::bind(MemberFunction,ObjectInstance);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution has one fault - *do while* loop is executed until `MsLimit` is elapsed. After `Timeout` started, `M` mutex is blocked and the call of `StopTimer` cannot break loop, because `stop` in `StopTimer` is set on true when `M` is released in `Timeout` what happens if `(T > MsLimit)` returns true and function ends. BTW, the use of `mutex` is redundant, because `Stop` is atomic.

You can use one of timers from boost library instead of creating your own one.

The code below uses `boost::asio::high_resolution_timer` (boost 1.55 version has it):

```
class Timer 
{
public:
  Timer (int ms)
  : timer(io), ms(ms) {}

  ~Timer() {if(t.joinable()) t.join();}

  void Start() {
    t = std::thread( [this]()
    {
      timer.expires_from_now(std::chrono::milliseconds(ms));
      timer.async_wait([this](const boost::system::error_code& ec) // start async wait
        { // lambda is called when timeout expired or error occures
          if (!ec) // if there is no error, call function
            NotifyWaitingThreadFunction();
        });
      io.run(); // process async operations
    });
  }

  void Stop() {
    timer.cancel();
  }

  template<class T>
  void AssignFunction(T* ObjectInstance, void (T::*MemberFunction)())
  {
      NotifyWaitingThreadFunction = std::bind(MemberFunction,ObjectInstance);
  }
private:
  boost::asio::io_service io; // needed for timer
  boost::asio::high_resolution_timer timer;
  std::thread t;
  int ms;
  std::function<void()> NotifyWaitingThreadFunction;
};
```

In `Start` method thread is created where we set value of timeout in ms, timer is started by `async_wait`. Lambda passed into `async_wait` is called when timeout expired or an error occures. So if there is no error, you can call `NotifyWaitingThreadFunction`. To stop timer use `Stop` method. Stop cancels started aynchronous operation then lambda is called with ec == `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted`. In this case lambda ends without calling `NotifyWaitingThreadFunction`.